# My c++ application appears nameless in windows 8 task manager

Tags: winapi

I have a C++ background application that I wrote quite some time ago. I just noticed after upgrading to windows 8 that in task manager, it appears as nameless. It has an entry out there, with the default app icon but no name. I rebuilt the application with VS 2012 on this machine, verified that the project properties has all names correct, also tried adding a resource file with version information but nothing helped. It still appears nameless in Windows 8 task manager.

Thanks,